# Size of array created dynamically doesn't match

Tags: c++, c, arrays, malloc

I think I am missing something simple there but I can't understand why I get this error.

I have an array with raw data I want to convert to double. I also have size of this array:

```
resWavFile0.resampledSingalData // array with data
resWavFile0.length // size of my array
```

If I want to display it, then it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++) 
{
    cout << "\n" << *((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i) / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

No crashes at all, I get all my values displayed in double. But now I would like to save those values in separate array so I create:

```
double* singnalToProcess0;
```

And because resWavFile0.length might change I need to allocate my array dynamically:

```
singnalToProcess0 = (double*) malloc(resWavFile0.length * sizeof(double));
```

Also I can set values of each memory block to 0:

```
memset(singnalToProcess0, 0, resWavFile0.length * sizeof(double));
```

But now I want to insert my doubles inside:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++) 
{
    *(singnalToProcess0 + i) = *((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i) / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

And for example my resWavFile0.length value is 149077 but I get "0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x01f6d000) at i = 75074. If I try to extend size of array in malloc for example even like this:

```
singnalToProcess0 = (double*) malloc( 30* resWavFile0.length * sizeof(double));
```

I still get same error at 75074. If I work with other sample for example shorter or longer - it always crashes with this error near middle of iteration. Also static allocation doesn't work:

```
double* singnalToProcess0 = new double[149077];
```

Also crash near middle - at i = 75074...

Full code there:

```
//// transfer to double
singnalToProcess0 = (double*) malloc(resWavFile0.length * sizeof(double));
memset(singnalToProcess0, 0, resWavFile0.length * sizeof(double));

for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++) {
    *(singnalToProcess0 + i) = *((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i) / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
ResampledWavFile struct:

```
typedef struct ResampledWavFile
{
    short* resampledSingalData;
    int length;
} ResampledWavFile;
```

Edit2 now it works:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++)
{
    singnalToProcess0[i] = resWavFile0.resampledSignalData[i] / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

Edit3: I was mistaken and this is also possible:

```
singnalToProcess0 = new double[resWavFile0.length];
```

Comment: What's the type of resWavFile0? Can you show a code snippet of its declaration?

Comment: If you're using `malloc()`, you should not be using C++.  If you're using C++, you should be using `new`.  Please choose a language — one language — because the reasonable answers are very different depending on whether you code in C or C++.  (Yes, you can probably make the code work in both; you probably shouldn't, though.)

Comment: I am using C++ but I can't use new because resWavFile0.length is a calculated value. I've also added ResampledWavFile struct as requested. Code about filling the array is quite long because its low lvl intel library resampling method - but if I  try to display values inside both resampledSignalData and length I can access every of them.

Comment: You seem to be treating your input array of shorts as if it were an array of ints - this will not work of course. This is why casts are generally a code smell, and why you should probably stick to array indexing rather than messy pointer arithmetic and casts as above.

Comment: The reason it's crashing is because you are reading past the end of your short array by casting it to an int pointer. What I can't understand is why it doesn't crash when you output the values to cout.

Comment: `*((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i)` does not mean what you want. The cast has higher precedence than the `+`, so it changes the meaning of the `+i` (to mean "+4i bytes" rather than "+2i bytes", if you have 4-byte integers and 2-byte shorts). You want `(int)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData[i]`. (Or just `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData[i]`. You don't actually need the cast.)

Comment: Maybe you have corrupted process memory somewhere earlier in the code? Such things can have strange consequences.

Comment: @F1sherF1sher: So, what is the semantics of `resWavFile0.length` field? Is it the length of the original `short` array? Or is it the length of the reinterpreted `int` array? You are using it as if it is the latter. Are you sure this the the correct interpretation ?

Comment: I can see where I did the mistake. I somehow took for granted that *(singnalToProcess0 + i) equals to singnalToProcess0[i] what is not true. I moved by wrong offsets probably, answer given by G.Ko solved the problem. Thank you all for your comments and help.

Comment: @F1sher: You are confused. `*(singnalToProcess0 + i)` is always 100%  equivalent to `singnalToProcess0[i]`. It is always true, by definition.

Comment: @Fisher, it is absolutely true. Your mistake was that you were casting your array of shorts to int*. If you just remove (int*) from your code, it will work. Please unaccept the answer you accepted, as it is completely wrong and might mislead people who find this question in the future.

Comment: @F1sher: Your edit2 worked because of the changes you made on the right-hand side. Your rhs is now equivalent to `*(resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i)`. You effectively removed the cast to `int *`. Is this what you really want? And if so, why did you cast it to `int *` in the original code? Where did the original `int *` cast came from???

Comment: @F1sher: Your edit3 is indeed "possible", but it has absolutely nothing to do with the original problem and will not fix anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have noticed that the index at which you crash is very close to the half of your array. This is no coincidence, because the issue that you are hitting is due to the fact that you cast your array of shorts (that are usually 2  bytes long) to an array of ints (that are usually 4 bytes long). Rewrite your code like that, and it will work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++) {
    *(singnalToProcess0 + i) = *((short*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i) / (double)0x7fffffff; 
}
```

Or completely remove casting (remove `(short*)`), as it is not actually needed.

Also, you mentioned in the comments, that you cannot use `new` because your data has dynamic size. It is also inaccurate, you can always use `new` in place of `malloc` in C++, and should usually do it.

Comment: That's true. I am quite surprised as I had problem with using `new` few days ago somewhere. `singnalToProcess0 = new double[resWavFile0.length];` works.

Comment: Also, don't forget to `delete[] signalToProcess0` after you are done with it.

Comment: @F1sher: So, if you didn't really need that cast to `int *` on the right-hand side, why did you claim that your `cout << ...` cycle worked properly? There's no way it could've worked properly if that cast to `int *` was unjustified.

Comment: Probably after it reached 75074 index then some garbage was modified by  / (double)0x7fffffff and displayed me wrong data but I didn't notice it. Program didn't crash though and I was interested if I can access the memory after 75074 index. Because it didn't crash I thought size of array doesn't match and I am doing something wrong by allocating not enough memory.

Comment: @F1sher: It is not just about the crash. If that cast to `int *` was wrong, then the values printed for `i = 0, 1, 2 ...` would be completely wrong as well. I.e. the version with `(int *)` and the version without `(int *)` will print *different* values from the very beginning. So, which ones actually  look correct?

Answer (score 0):

Considering the definition of the `struct ResampledWavFile`

```
typedef struct ResampledWavFile
{
    short* resampledSingalData;
    int length;
} ResampledWavFile;
```

and assuming that an object of the type has `length` number of `short`s in `resampledSingalData`, the lines

```
for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++) 
{
    cout << "\n" << *((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i) / (double)0x7fffffff;
}
```

don't look right.

The expression

```
*((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i)
```

is equivalent to

```
int* ip = (int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData;
*(ip+i)
```

That will access out of bounds memory unless `sizeof(short) == sizeof(int)` in your platform.

If you change the line in the `for` loop to:

```
    short num = resWavFile0.resampledSingalData[i];
    cout << "\n" << num / (double)0x7fffffff;
```

you can avoid that problem. However, I don't understand how that will affect the accuracy of your numerical calculations.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question depends on what you really have to do. You haven't explained it clearly, but there seems to be several possibilities, depending on the semantics of the `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData` array and `resWavFile0.length` value. Only you know that semantics, we are not telepathic or clairvoyant here.

The possible interpretations include (under assumption that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(short) * 2`)

1. `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData` is declared as an array of `short` elements. If these `short` elements are your values and `resWavFile0.length` contains the length of the array, then all you need is

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++)
     singnalToProcess0[i] = 
       resWavFile0.resampledSignalData[i] / (double) 0x7fffffff;
   ```
2. If `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData` is supposed to be reinterpreted as an array of `int` values (composed of two consecutive shorts each), but `resWavFile0.length` contains the length of the `short` array, then `resWavFile0.length` is expected to be even and what you need is

   ```
   assert(resWavFile0.length % 2 == 0);

   for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length / 2; i++)
     singnalToProcess0[i] = 
       ((int *) resWavFile0.resampledSignalData[i]) / (double) 0x7fffffff;
   ```
3. If `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData` is supposed to be reinterpreted as an array of `int` values (composed of two consecutive shorts each) and `resWavFile0.length` contains the length of that `int` array, then what you need is

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < resWavFile0.length; i++)
     singnalToProcess0[i] = 
       ((int *) resWavFile0.resampledSignalData[i]) / (double) 0x7fffffff;
   ```

   But this is the same as your original variant, which is crashing, so apparently this interpretation is incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

`double`, `int`, `short` are not of the same size in the memory. Accessing with memory increment like `*(singnalToProcess0 + i)` is not getting the results you want, due to alignment stuff and other memory access stuff.
You should access them like regular arrays: `singnalToProcess0[i] = ...`. The same should be applied to `*((int*)resWavFile0.resampledSingalData+i)` to turn to `resWavFile0.resampledSingalData[i]`.

Comment: signalToProcess0[i]  is just a syntactic sugar for *(singnalToProcess0 + i)

Comment: Not for every type due to the size of the type

Comment: @G. Ko: Firstly, there's no difference between `singnalToProcess0[i]` and `*(singnalToProcess0 + i)`. They are the same *for every type*, no exceptions. Secondly, how do you know what the OP wants? Maybe that's exactly what the OP wants: to reinterpret each pair of `short`s as an `int`. And maybe `length` actually stores the number of `int`s, not the number of `short`s.

Comment: What I said is the case for every type. When you add 1 to a pointer, pointer gets shifted by the size of the type, so *(ptr + i) is exactlly the same as ptr[i], no matter what type ptr points to

Comment: @AnT, he's saying strictly that he wants to convert shorts to double.

Comment: @G. Ko: I don't see him saying that. Where? Moreover, he said that his `cout << ...` cycle worked properly. It wouldn't work properly if the conversion to `int` was unjustified.

Comment: @AnT, read this line: "But now I would like to save those values in separate array so I create:". So apparently my answer was correct. Down votes were unnecessary.

Comment: @G. Ko: Your answer is incorrect because it is suggesting that `*(ptr + i)` is not the same as `ptr[i]`, while it **always is**. The error in OP code was casting the array to (int*).